# CakePHP Shell Script Environment Setting

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new to shell development in Cake. The problem I am facing is to setting datasource in the script itself. My database.php is;

```
function __construct() 
{ 
    if(getenv('ENVIRONMENT') == 'staging') {
        $this->default = $this->staging;
    } else {
        $this->default = $this->production;
    }
}
```

So, I am setting database based on the web server's environment setting. Naturally, php-cli can't access this variable. What I end up doing is to create a cakephp shell task.

```
class SelectEnvTask extends Shell {

    public function execute() 
    {
        App::Import('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
        $configs = ConnectionManager::enumConnectionObjects();

        if (!is_array($configs) || empty($configs)) {
            $this->out('Error! No database configuration has been found.');
        }

        $connections = array_keys($configs);

        if(!isset($this->args[0])) {
            $this->out('Error! Please enter one of the environment settings as an argument: ' . implode('/', $connections) . 
                "\n\n" . 'eg. ./Console/cake *script_name* *environment*', 2);
            exit(1);
        }

        if(!in_array($this->args[0], $connections)) {
            $this->out($this->args[0] . ' environment could not be found!', 2);
            exit(1);
        }

        //hacky solution until finding a better one
        $models = App::objects('Model');
        foreach($models as $model) {
            ClassRegistry::init($model)->setDataSource($this->args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

This works correctly, however as you see in the below of the task, I get all the model names and change their DB connection, which is not a good practice. I also don't want to set more variables into the database class and would like to handle these in shells/tasks.

Is there any more elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks,

Comment: Hey merinn, did you get an answer for that? I am having the same doubt about it. How to implement an elegant solution based on a server enviroment for both needs, Web and Console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a far more elegant solution.  Add the following method to your shell or task, and then execute it whenever you need to in order to change your data profile (listed in app/Config/database.php) on the fly:

```
function change_database_profile($database = 'default') {
    $connected = ConnectionManager::getDataSource($database);
    if($connected->isConnected()) { 
        return true; 
    }   
    return false;
}
```